# TreeMap Sorted Positions Access

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

If I want to check that the value present at first index position in a TreeMap is xyz then do xyz
Else if the value present at the first index position is abc then do abc. How I will be able to write this? Because I want to access arranged indices in a TreeMap. I want to access sorted keys of a TreeMap one by one in order. Help required

Comment: I don't "get it."  If the map be sorted already, then what is preventing your from just checking the first entry using `firstEntry()` ?

Comment: I have total 8 keys and values in a treemap and I want to access each key (arranged in ascending order) one by one. Not only first and last entry Sir. Is there a way? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: *"after sort in a TreeMap"* What do you mean by "after sort"? A `TreeMap` cannot be unsorted, so there is no such thing as *before* sort, and hence no such thing as *after* sort.

Comment: *"I want to access each key (arranged in ascending order) one by one"* That's called iterating, and you do that by calling `keySet()`.

Comment: Have you tried using iterator of the set returned by the "entrySet()" method? [Please try to rephrase your problem, it's very confusing]

Comment: When keys and values are given in a TreeMap, unsorted values in the key can be given using put() function. By using the TreeMap object and println() function, we can display the whole keys and values sorted. I want to access each sorted key one by one. @Andreas

Comment: You can say I want to fetch all keys one by one in a treemap. How can I do it with iterator? @HungryCoder

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/treemap-in-java-with-example/

Comment: @HungryCoder Raw types? Oh the horror...

Comment: My condition statement is something like this ,, if the value at first index is abc then do abc. Like the function firstEntry() .. The difference is that I want to access each entry. I don't want to give the value of key. I want to access keys on the basis of order which is made by TreeMap @HungryCoder

Comment: The `TreeMap` itself is **always sorted**. It cannot be unsorted. Sure you can put new key/value pairs into the map in any order, but the Map itself is always ordered, hence there is no "after sorting" of the **Map**. To access each sorted key "one by one", create an iterator using `map.keySet().iterator()`, then get them *one at a time*, by calling `next()`, then `next()`, then `next()`, then `next()`, then `next()`, until `hasNext()` returns false.

Comment: @Andreas , can you give some link for this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this code iterates through all the keys in sorted order
treeMap.keySet().forEach(key -> {
    //use key to do whatever you need
});
```

## Edit

```
//this code iterates through all entries (from first, second, third, ... to last)
tree.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    key = entry.getKey();
    value = entry.getValue();
    //use key and value to do whatever you need
});
```

## Edit2

```
//this codes finds the first key whose value equals the desired value
Object key = tree.entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(desiredValue))
                            .map(Entry::getKey)
                            .findFirst()
                            .get();
```

Comment: Sir, Is there a way like firstEntry() function specifically access first key value in TreeMap? I want to access each entry in this way.

Comment: On first iteration, if key's value == desired value .. How will I write this Sir?

Comment: I want to be specific on iterations Sir

Comment: @Ammarah See my second edit if you want to find the first key whose value equals the desired value

Comment: Sir, you have used here findFirst() function for the first key. For second, third and so on up to 8, which function should I use?

Comment: @Ammarah Okay, if you want to do something different for each key, go with BenM's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and ugliest hack might simply be

```
List<KeyType> keyList = new ArrayList<>(myTreeMap.keySet());
KeyType nthKey = keyList.get(nthIndex);
```

but I'd be asking myself why am I using a `TreeMap` in the first place, when I want to look up entries by index? Would it be more efficient to use a `List` and call `sort`?

Comment: If I use list and sort then how will I do this Sir?